# Align sprite with bottom edge of camera

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a 2d game in Unity. I've got a sprite that will serve as the background, so I'm trying to line it up with the bottom of the camera.

Right now, I have it centered horizontally using this code:

```
#pragma strict


function Start () {
    transform.position = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0.5, 0, 5));
}

function Update () {

}
```

Which results in something like this:
[image: Diagram of what I have vs. what I want]

Instead, I would like the sprite to be aligned vertically so that the bottom of the sprite is lined up with the bottom of the camera (as shown in the diagram above).

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way? You can put that sprite on a empty Game Object, and set pivot of parent to bottom of sprite. Then You will move that parent object instead of sprite directly.